# How to display a list of objects containing many-to-many relations in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Entry(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date = models.DateField()
  tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

In a view I create a list of Entry object and want to show the elements in the template:

```
   {% for entry in entries %}
     {{ entry.title }}
     {{ entry.date }}
   <!--  {% for tag in entry.tags %} {{ tag }} {% endfor %} -->
   {% endfor %}
```

And with this template code it generates the following TemplateSyntaxError pointing to the template's first line (for tag):

**Caught TypeError while rendering: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable**

The entries variable is a list:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(user=user_id)
entries = list(entries)
entries.sort(key=lambda x: x.id, reverse=False)
```

Do you know what can be the problem here and how to resolve this issue?

I'm new to Django, so any suggestions how to debug the templates may be helpful.

**Update**

I get the same error even with this template:

```
{% for entry in entries.all %}
<!-- everything is commented out here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you converting 'entries' into a list and sorting it in Python?  That's very inefficient.  You should use 'order_by' to get the database to do the sorting.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no need to turn the entries QuerySet into a list.  Additionally, you can let the DB do the sorting using [order_by](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields).

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).order_by('id')
```

Add `.all` to get all the values from a relationship (just like `Entry.objects.all()`).

```
entry.tags.all
```

You can try this in the shell as well (I use ipython so your output may look different):

```
$ ./manage.py shell
# ...
In [1]: from yourproject.models import Entry, Tags
In [2]: entry = Entry.objects.all()[0]
In [3]: entry.tags
Out[3]: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x...>
In [4]: entry.tags.all()  # for an entry with no tags.
Out[4]: []
In [5]: # add a few tags
In [6]: for n in ('bodywork', 'happy', 'muscles'):
   ...:     t, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=n)
   ...:     entry.tags.add(t)
In [7]: entry.tags.all()
Out[7]: [<Tag: ...>, <Tag: ...>, <Tag: ...>]
```

And if you want to call out the entries with zero tags use [for..empty](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty).

```
{% for tag in entry.tags.all %}
    {{ tag.name }}
{% empty %}
    No tags!
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Actually I have already tried adding .all. But in the template side I get en empty list.

Comment: Updated the shell code to make sure at least one entry has a tag.  Added a template example using for..empty to show a way to indicate that there were no tags.

Comment: The problem is that it works in shell. But in the template I get nothing, though the entires contains elements.

Comment: If you are still doing your list(...) stuff, then make sure you do not add .all in the template.  Also, try adding your view code to the question.  Or maybe just add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the view and take a look at the variables you have.  Alternatively you can try looking at the variables with the django-debug-toolbar  http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: best idea, save my day.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the solution of your query,

Verifying your solution by giving an example

Suppose a book have number of tags, so in order to display all the tags of a book on template can be like this

```
{% for tag in book.tags.all %}
  {{ tag.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

where the model of Tag is like,

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % unicode(self.name)
```

Answer (score 5):

OK. I found the problem. I had some incorrect code which was commented out. But Django processed that code. So html comments didn't work here. I fixed this and it all worked like a charm.

So if you didn't know - **the html comments don't prevent template processing**.

This is because the template is being processed by Django first then HTML is rendered by browser.

Comment: You will probably enjoy {# onliner comment #} and {% comment %} ... {% endcomment %}.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#comment

Answer (score 4):

The above from istruble is correct but if your question contains all of your code you need to specify a property in your template:

```
   {% for entry in entries %}
     {{ entry.title }}
     {{ entry.date }}
     {% for tag in entry.tags.all %} {{ tag.name }} {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

or a default **unicode** function to your model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name
```